# Error message converting from markdown to PDF

Tags: markdown

I am using MacOSX (Yosemite 10.10) and I have a problem trying to convert from markdown to PDF.

The error message is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.268 for Windows the file is at *C:\Windows
```

[image]

Comment: We need more information than this to adequately address your problem.

Comment: How could I give you more information? It is the only message that I get.
Edit: I have edited the message with a snapshot

Comment: @Xatpy: The visual output from the terminal is far more helpful that some of the coded errors using markdown on this network.

Comment: thanks Werner, but I was asking **how** could I give you more details.

Comment: I think this question is off-topic though, as it deals with Markdown, not (La)TeX.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that `\Windows` is considered as a macro (control sequence) that does not exist. However, you are probably interested in displaying the literal folder `C:\Windows` (say).

Similar to how such entries are escaped here on [TeX - LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com), you need to use backticks to escape inline code:

```
`C:\Windows`
```

So, use

```
... for Windows the file is at `C:\Windows` ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Werner.
But my question is: where should I edit that command? In what file?

Comment: @Xatpy: The error references `l.268` (or line 268), which should be in `documentation.md`.